# How do I transfer my Disney Digital Copy movie to iTunes using Lion?

Tags: itunes, icloud, powerpc, movie, drm

I want to try this "Digital Copy" to iCloud movie deal but when I pop in the DVD it says:

> You can't open the application Up because PowerPC applications are no longer supported.

Is there any other work around besides using Snow Leopard or a Windows PC?

I just want to watch Disney Pixar's Up on my iPad.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree 100% with Adam's answer that **DRM is a horrible thing**, and "Digital Copy" in particular is a bad joke; see [here](http://blogs.computerworld.com/digital_copy_a_feature_thats_no_feature).

However, I'll point out you **can** still watch your *Up!* Digital Copy on your Mac, even if OS X Lion doesn't support the PowerPC-based installer software on Disney's antiquated disc.  I had the same issue and solved it as follows:

1. Launch iTunes.
2. Put the disc in your Mac's DVD drive.
3. In the left navigation area, select the disc.
4. You should see a page on the right asking you to *Enter Code*.  Enter the unique activation code that came with your copy of *Up!*, then click *Redeem*.
5. Authenticate with your iTunes credentials, when prompted.  (Assumption: You have an iTunes account, a working Internet connection, and your Digital Copy code is valid, not expired, and not yet redeemed.)
6. After authenticating with iTunes (the service), iTunes (the program) will proceed to *copy* the now-authorized movie content from your *Up!* "Digital Copy" disc to your Mac.
7. Find the new title in your "Movies" library.  Watch it on your Mac<sup>*</sup>.

All the details, including screenshots, can be found at:

- [Apple Support - Transferring or downloading an iTunes Digital Copy](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1539).

* **Worth mentioning:**  Even after you get your "Digital Copy" into iTunes on your Mac, it *remains protected* and can only be played back on a device authorized to play back purchases from your iTunes account.  Consequently, you may still prefer using another extraction method on the original movie, in order to yield a liberated version of your content unencumbered with such restrictions.

Summary: DRM is *still* a horrible thing, even with the workaround above.

(p.s. FWIW, this method also worked (for me) for non-Disney titles such as *Dr. Seuss' Horton Hears a Who!*, from Twentieth Century Fox, and *Despicable Me*, from Universal Studios.  Mentioning this in case somebody else finds this answer but has a non-Disney disc; i.e. it doesn't seem to matter whether the "Digital Copy" is Disney or not, the above method should work to authorize & copy the content to iTunes.)

Comment: Thanks Chris, I am sure I will be coming back to this one.

Comment: Thanks Chris. I also tried that but I think my problem was that the code was expired. I keep the DVD incase I need a liberated copy but having the movie in iCloud is very useful.

Comment: I got it to work even though it was expired. Maybe they don't expire anymore?

Answer (score 3):

Movie DRM is a horrible thing - it's a sad fact that your best option is probably to torrent a HD h264 copy of the movie, and just feel OK about it because you paid for the physical media - even though you can't do anything with it.

I don't even know a way to install Rosetta to Lion - system binaries are no longer "Fat" so even if the installer could be fooled it will probably not work. I know of people who have used it in a VM running Snow Leopard, or who have dual booted with Snow Leopard just to keep ability to run PPC-only apps, but I don't know anyone who has installed Rosetta to Lion.

Comment: I would disagree that torrenting is the best option and not only because of the legality around it but also I do not get iCloud's streaming capability (at least easily).    Running SL in a VM is a good idea though.

Comment: Fair enough. I just figure that by paying for it once you have done the right thing and should reasonably expect to be able to watch the movie for your lifetime without maintaining old software to do it. Of course the Hollywood position is that you pay for it again every time their cunning plan makes it stop working. I have many DVDs collected worldwide and no DVD player save what is in my computers - I'll rip them to h264 with no qualms. I don't share them but the act of decrypting make me just as much a criminal in studio eyes, the only difference being damages they could sue for.

Answer (score -1):

Macs are a bit dumb when it comes to this stuff. New ones work well, but if you got the disk a few years ago when Digital Copy was first included, basically you have to ignore the instructions included with the DVD/Bluray and do the following:

1. Load Itunes
2. Put the Disk in
3. Itunes will automatically load the "redeem this item" page
4. Put your code in and press redeem...

Now it will load. I know Chris already gave this answer, but his second instruction of "In the left navigation area, select the disc." is confusing, so I've worded it better.

Comment: Instead of writing a new answer just to reword a small step in someone else's answer, use the provided [edit](http://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/72938/edit) link under their answer to improve it.